# Abstract factory pattern instead of generics - how?

Tags: c#, generics, polymorphism, factory-pattern

I have a generic interface:

```
public interface IReader<T> where T: Result
{
   IEnumerable<T> ReadResults();
}
```

where `Result` is a base class and is extended into `DetailedResult`:

```
public class Result
{
    // ...
}

public class DetailedResult : Result
{
    // ... ...
}
```

Now I have two concrete types for `IReader`, each of this implementation returns different type, specific to the reader type:

```
public class DefaultResultReader<Result> : IReader<Result>
{
    IEnumerable<Result> ReadResults();
}
```

and

```
public class DetailedResultReader<DetailedResult> : IReader<DetailedResult>
{
    IEnumerable<DetailedResult> ReadResults();
}
```

The structure presented above uses generics. I would like to get rid of it if possible, and have some kind of a factory which would create a concrete implementation of `IReader` for me - `DefaultResultReader.ReadResults()` method must return `Result` while `DetailedResultReader.ReadResults()` must return `DetailedResult`

My question is how should the abstract factory look for this structure - how to design it so that I can create specific `IReader` object as requested ?

Comment: Could you elaborate? What is your question?

Comment: I need a factory so that I can create different `IReader` objects - Each of concrete implementations of `Ireader` has specific method return type.

Comment: It all depends on what your factory will look like. If you want it to be fully generic, then you have a bunch of issues to consider. But if you want to predefine which type will return what reader then it's easier as what you really need is to check `IReader<T> GetReader<T>() where T : Result`. But still, this question is really broad in it's current state.

Comment: It is hard to describe it more clearly - right now what I have presented is based on generic - but I would like to get rid of it and have a factory which would create me a specific implementation of `IReader` - `DefaultResultReader.ReadResults()`  always returns `Result` and `DetailedResultReader.ReadResults()` always returns `DetailedReader`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i didn't get exactly what you want, but i guess you expect something the following :

```
public interface IReader<T> where T : Result
{
    IEnumerable<T> ReadResults();
}

public class Result
{
}

public class DetailedResult : Result
{
    // ... ...
}

public class DefaultResultReader : IReader<Result>
{
    public IEnumerable<Result> ReadResults()
    {
        return null;
    }
}

public class DetailedResultReader : IReader<DetailedResult>
{
    public IEnumerable<DetailedResult> ReadResults()
    {
        return null;
    }
}

public abstract class ResultReaderAbsractFactory
{
    public abstract IReader<Result> CreareDefaultResultReader();
    public abstract IReader<DetailedResult> CreareDetailedResultReader();
}

public class ConcreteResultRaderFactory : ResultReaderAbsractFactory
{
    public override IReader<Result> CreareDefaultResultReader()
    {
        return new DefaultResultReader();
    }

    public override IReader<DetailedResult> CreareDetailedResultReader()
    {
        return new DetailedResultReader();
    }
}
```

Comment: This adds an unnecessary class into the mix. As you are already using interfaces, I would expect that you'd create one for the Factory itself, which pretty much nullifies the point of the abstract class. The _abstract_ in Abstracy Factory doesn't require the use of an actual abstract class -  you gain nothing from having it.

Answer (score 2):

If the `DefaultResultReader<Result>` will always return `IEnumerable<Result>`, and `DetailedResultReader<DetailedResult>` will always return `IEnumerable<DetailedResult>`, I would suggest making the classes

```
public class DefaultResultReader : IReader<Result>
{
    IEnumerable<Result> ReadResults();
}
```

and

```
public class DetailedResultReader : IReader<DetailedResult>
{
    IEnumerable<DetailedResult> ReadResults();
}
```

You then have the abstract factory class

```
public class ReaderFactory
{
    public IReader<Result> CreateDefaultResultReader()
    {
        return new DefaultResultReader();
    }

    public IReader<DetailedResult> CreateDetailedResultReader()
    {
        return new DetailedResultReader();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I could do it that way :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make it fully generic, meaning that you do not have to extend this class even if you create new reader types.  You can simply make something like this :

```
public static class ResultReaderFactory
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> ReadResults<T>() where T : Result
    {
        IReader<T> reader = GetReader<T>();
        if(reader != null)
        {
            return reader.ReadResults();   
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static IReader<T> GetReader<T>() where T : Result
    {
        // get the first reader implementation from the list
        // that matches the generic definition
        IReader<T> reader = _instances
                            .FirstOrDefault(
                                r => r.GetType()
                                    .GetInterfaces()
                                    .Any(
                                        i => i == typeof(IReader<T>)
                                    )
                            ) as IReader<T>;
        return reader;
    }

    // placeholder for all objects that implement IReader
    static IEnumerable<object> _instances;

    static ResultReaderFactory()
    {
        // register all instances of classes,
        // that implements IReader interface
        _instances = typeof(ResultReaderFactory)
                     .Assembly
                     .GetTypes()
                     .Where(
                         t => t.GetInterfaces()
                             .Any(
                                 i => i.Name
                                     .StartsWith("IReader`1")
                             )
                     )
                     .Select(t => Activator.CreateInstance(t));  
    }
}
```

To use this you just have to make classes that implements `IReader<T>` in the same Assembly that `ResultReaderFactory` is. Then you can just forget about that factory object and simply call it whenever you want with :

```
ResultReaderFactory.GetReader<DetailedResult>();
// or assuming you've created class ExtremalyDetailedResult
// and ExtremalyDetailedResultReader
ResultReaderFactory.GetReader<ExtremalyDetailedResult>();
```

---

This will read all types that implements `IReader<T>` whenever you start your application. Then it will pack all of those classes ( already instantiated ) in to the `List<object>` so you can use them later on. This is really slow though because it uses reflections and Linq to determine which `IReader<T>` implementation to return.

[try this online](http://rextester.com/JKXD49650)